# What is the angle that an Archimedean conical spiral makes with the floor?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have a spiral in the form $$r = r_0(1-{\theta\over2\pi k }) \{r \ge 0\}$$ where $r_0$ is an initial radius, and $k$ is the number of turns. (It is a spiral that decays from $r_0$ to $0$ as $\theta$ increases) and I want to have this mapped out to a cone (apex of $2\phi$ pointing down) so that the gradient of the spiral (and hence the angle between the spiral and the floor) is constant, and $r_0$ matches that of the cone. If this is the case, and when given: $r_0, h, \phi $, and $k$; what is the angle between the right-cones hypotenuse and the spiral track?

Comment: How do you map the spiral from the plane to the cone? By parallel projection in the direction of the cone's axis?

Comment: @jflipp yes, I guess. I'm using this so that I can build a reasonably accurate one out of paper, so maybe it doesn't even matter. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined main objective $ (r- \theta) $ relation on cone:
 $$ r = r_0(1-{\theta\over2\pi }) $$

for Archimedean spiral polar projection.

$ \theta\over2\pi $ serves the same purpose as $k$ which can be conveniently avoided.

So parametric coordinates of the spiral are:

$$ (x, y, z) = r_0(1-{\theta\over2\pi }) ( cos\,\theta , sin\,\theta, cot \, \phi) $$

If $\psi$ is angle made between tangent and circumferential direction we derive using differential geometry:

$$ sin\,\phi \,tan\,\psi\, ( 2\pi - \theta ) = 1  $$

The spiral is written on this cone with $ r=0 \,@ \, z=0, r_0 =1,\phi = \pi/6. $ The angle $\psi $ can be computed at any point desired.

EDIT1: Please note it is much easier to go from general case using more comprehensive methods to special ones than the other way round.

EDIT2: 
Here $\psi$ angle is made between tangent and parallel circle or ground.If $\psi$ is constant, it is called a *Loxodrome* ; the requirement for x- y projection to be an Archimedean spiral *conflicts* with $\psi$ constancy, i.e., either this or that, mutually exclusive.

It is recommended to learn about geodesics at this stage. Clairaut's Law states $ r \cdot cos\psi $ is constant. If $\beta $ is made with generator, then $ r \cdot sin \beta $ is constant. It is good opportune entry into differential geometry.

EDIT3: If OP meant or implied by gradient (height gained by climbing unit length of arc ) as $ dz/ds = \cos \phi \cdot  \cos \psi $ , then $ \psi$ should be constant as a Loxodrome since $\phi$ is constant for a cone. Its development would be a logarithmic spiral.

[image: ArchSprlonCone]
[image: ArchimedenSpiral XYview]

Comment: I like this a lot! However I don't think I stated (sorry) that I wanted the spiral to have a constant gradient if that makes any sense. The way yours is defined $\psi$ changes, whereas in mine c would be constant, which I should've defined as the angle between the tangent and the cone edge. This also means that k is important, because $k \propto c$. I'll get right on changing these definitions so that it is more clear. BTW, If I knew anything about LaTeX graphing whatsoever I would make lovely 3D diagrams such as you did.

Comment: This ^ said, I may find this useful in the near future!

Comment: @SamWalls: Choose any CAS, Mathematica (which created above images), Maple, Matlab &c.

Comment: haha, while I would love to get these programs, I don't have all that much money to spend on math. I'll maybe try and convince someone at my school to consider wolfram mathematica.

Comment: By gradient, maybe a better way of describing it would be that the height decreases at a constant rate. Is this what you thought I meant? I'm trying to extend this to a ball rolling down the path. As long as I can find: the radius at any point $\theta$ and the vertical /tangential slope (this gradient or angle that I've been jabbering about) at any point I should be fine. I really appreciate this by the way. All this differential geometry seems a little beyond me, but anthing is possible.

Comment: hello, would you mind if I were to use the image you created (the spiral projection onto a cone) for the physics investigation in question? I eventually took a simpler approach, but the image you created is so beautiful, I would like to use it on the front cover. You will be meantioned, for both this image, and in introducing loxodromes to me.

Comment: Please go ahead. Shall also make any changes needed for publication in a wider context.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. What would you like to chat on? Does stack exchange have a chat feature? This isn't a publication really, I suppose it could be one day, but its not that earth-shattering. Its a physics investigation for school.

Comment: An image with straight lines and their orthogonal lines on cone may interest you.

Comment: that would aid how I actually construct the cone. But in the case of my project, the spiral which I project is no longer an archimedean, but a logarithmic spiral, so that I can exploit the loxodrome-properties. $r = r_0 e ^ {-\cot (\psi) \theta}$ where $\psi$ is the pitch angle of the spiral. In my case, $r_0 = 0.313$ and $\psi = \frac{85\pi}{180}$

Comment: sorry, but my investigation is already too long, I don't think I can inlcude any more pictures / graphs. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Loxodromes when developed flat are *Logarithmic Spirals* as already stated. Good luck for your project!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer, correct me if i'm wrong. Consider a half turn over the spiral:

- the vertical displacement will be $h\over 2k$
- the horizontal displacement will be equal to $r_0$
- when a triangle is drawn with these in mind there is a right angled triangle such that $$\tan(c+\phi) = {2kr_0 \over h}$$

then transposing and solving for k and c we get:
$$ k = {h\tan(c+\phi)\over 2 r_0}$$
or
$$ c = \arctan ({2kr_0\over h}) - \phi$$
**EDIT** this "$c$" is for the angle between the cones edge and the spiral, not as the question originally asked, between the spiral and the floor. The angle between the spiral and the floor will be $\pi - (c+\phi)$

Again, please tell me if you think I am wrong or have any questions.